# How would one spec ActiveRecord::Base.find(something).method with should_receive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, arel

Let's say we have the following code:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.fix_published_times
    where(:published => true, :published_at => nil).limit(5).each do |post
      post.fix_published_at!
    end
  end
end
```

**How should I spec** `Post#fix_published__at!` **with should_receive?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along this lines of this should work:

```
  mock_posts = [mock("post 1"), mock("post 2")]
  Post.should_receive(:where).with(:published => true, :published_at => nil).and_return(mock_posts)
  mock_posts.each do |mp|
    mp.should_receive(:fix_published_at!).and_return(true)
  end
  Post.fix_published_times
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't clarify but what I want to spec is the `Post#fix_published_at!` method

Comment: @vrinek Updated answer based on clarification.

Comment: @Ant thx. Now for replacing `each` with `find_each`, do you think I should ask a new question?

Comment: @Ant, I am trying to do the same but with `where(<args>).find_each do |post|` but after the `. and_return(mock_posts)` it complains about Array not understanding for_each. Doing the same with `stub(ActiveRecord::Relation)` instead of the mocks, raises no error but I don't know how to get access to the find_each block.

Comment: @vrinek You don't need the where if you're using find_each, you can just do find_each(conditions here). Then just stub find_each instead of where in your test.